# Javascript reactJs css in javascript in external file

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using reactjs and trying to get me css inside javascript and finally read the css from an external js file.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

var styles = {
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    border: '5px solid green',
    borderRadius: 2
  }
};

var myComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div style={styles.container}>
        {this.props.name}
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

This works fine but what I need to do is to put the css in an external file.
So I've created a file called general.css.js

And I tried to import it:

```
import styles from './components/general.css';
```

I add this import to the top of the page with the other imports.

The problem is that it's not reading the styles.

What I'm I doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by an external file ? Css or js file ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make a new file and put this code in it.

```
export const style = { container : { 
  padding: 20,
  border: '5px solid green', 
  borderRadius: 2 } 
};
```

Now in your component file.

```
import * as styles from './style/location/filename'
```

Now you can use styles in your render function.

```
return (
    <div style={styles.style.main}>
      <h3 style={styles.style.header}>Vote for your favorite hack day idea</h3>
    </div>
  );
```

Comment: But I want to do it this way: var styles = {
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    border: '5px solid green',
    borderRadius: 2
  }
}; but in an external file

Comment: @PaulTenna2000 I have updated the answer as per your requirements. Check it out.

Answer (score 3):

You can directly import your css file in js.

`import './style/app.css';`

`app.css`

`.page {
background-color:#fafafa;
}`

and you can use this class in React component like below.

`<div className="page">`

Hope it works!!!!

Comment: But I want to do it this way: var styles = {
  container: {
    padding: 20,
    border: '5px solid green',
    borderRadius: 2
  }
}; but in an external file

Comment: can you use style={styles.styles.container} in react component ?

Comment: Perfect. Along with you should appropriate loaders for css

Comment: if u want to use style in external file just make `export const style = {container:{ padding: 20, border: '5px solid green', borderRadius: 2 } }; ` then in component js `import * as styles from './style/location/filename'` and you can use that as `<div style={styles.style.container} >`. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little tool that automates translation from CSS to JSON representation.

Worth checking [that](http://staxmanade.com/CssToReact/) out.

Note how the translation adds _ underscores:

```
div.redcolor { color:red; }
div:hover { color:blue; }
```

Into:

```
{"div_redcolor":{"color":"red"},"div_hover":{"color":"blue"}}
```

Note how the Vishwas Chauhan used starred method of ES6 import export:

[image]

In case you use this tool you get one big object, and you can use any method.